# VBA code in Excel is very slow (copying 130 cells takes 15 sec)

Tags: vba, performance, excel

In excel VBA I have two tables. I copy cells from the first two the second. The structure of the tables are different so I copy cell by cell. There is only 130 cells to be copied, still it takes about 15 seconds. How can I speed it up?

It seems that if I run the macro from the VBA editor it is quicker but still needs at least 10 second. If I run it from excel then I can see selecting and the copying of the cells. So it is slow.

Should I try to assign value between the cells instead of copy? Or VBA is just slow?

```
Public Sub PasteValueRowsIntoAccountDateTable()
Dim rowNumberOfTarget As Integer
Dim rowNumberOfSource As Integer        
Sheets("Utolsó hó").Select
Dim myTable As Excel.ListObject
Dim myRow As Excel.ListRow    
Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Utolsó_hó")
For Each myRow In myTable.ListRows
    rowNumberOfSource = myRow.Range.row
    Sheets("Számla dátum").Select
    rowNumberOfTarget = Range("Számla_dátum[[#Totals],[Előző Id]]").Value2 + 1
    Rows(rowNumberOfTarget & ":" & rowNumberOfTarget).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Call PasteValueRowIntoAccountDateTable(rowNumberOfSource, rowNumberOfTarget)
Next myRow
End Sub

Public Sub PasteValueRowIntoAccountDateTable(ByVal rowNumberOfSource As Integer, ByVal rowNumberOfTarget As Integer)
Call FillDownInAccountDateTable("Előző Id", rowNumberOfTarget)
Call FillDownInAccountDateTable("Havi nettó hozam", rowNumberOfTarget)
Call PasteValueCellIntoAccountDateTable(rowNumberOfSource, "Számlanév", rowNumberOfTarget)
Call PasteValueCellIntoAccountDateTable(rowNumberOfSource, "Aktuális dátum", rowNumberOfTarget)
Call PasteValueCellIntoAccountDateTable(rowNumberOfSource, "Nettó számla érték", rowNumberOfTarget)
Call PasteValueCellIntoAccountDateTable(rowNumberOfSource, "Nettó nem realizált hozam", rowNumberOfTarget)
Call PasteValueCellIntoAccountDateTable(rowNumberOfSource, "Havi nettó realizált hozam", rowNumberOfTarget)
Call PasteValueCellIntoAccountDateTable(rowNumberOfSource, "Havi tranzfer saját számlák között", rowNumberOfTarget)
Call PasteValueCellIntoAccountDateTable(rowNumberOfSource, "Havi jövedelem", rowNumberOfTarget)
Call PasteValueCellIntoAccountDateTable(rowNumberOfSource, "Havi költés", rowNumberOfTarget)
End Sub

Public Sub FillDownInAccountDateTable(ByVal columnName As String, ByVal rowNumberOfTarget As Integer)
Dim columnNumberOfTarget As Integer        
columnNumberOfTarget = TableColumnToIndex("Számla dátum", "Számla_dátum[" & columnName & "]")
Sheets("Számla dátum").Select
Cells(rowNumberOfTarget, columnNumberOfTarget).Select
Selection.FillDown
End Sub

Public Sub PasteValueCellIntoAccountDateTable(ByVal rowNumberOfSource As Integer, ByVal columnName As String, ByVal rowNumberOfTarget As Integer)
Dim columnNumberOfTarget As Integer
Dim columnNumberOfSource As Integer        
columnNumberOfSource = TableColumnToIndex("Utolsó hó", "Utolsó_hó[" & columnName & "]")
Sheets("Utolsó hó").Select
Cells(rowNumberOfSource, columnNumberOfSource).Copy
columnNumberOfTarget = TableColumnToIndex("Számla dátum", "Számla_dátum[" & columnName & "]")
Sheets("Számla dátum").Select
Cells(rowNumberOfTarget, columnNumberOfTarget).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Select and Copy/Paste are slow commands. Avoid Select and use `Range.Copy Destination:=TopLeftCell`.   But the omission of `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` is the cause of most of your lost time.

Comment: You should watch this series [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) . This one is a must: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&t=2805s&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the Table names.  My version of Excel doesn't allow accent marks in table names.

[image]

```
Public Sub PasteValueRowsIntoAccountDateTable2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim SourceTable As Excel.ListObject, TargetTable As Excel.ListObject
    Dim TargetRow As Integer
    Dim ColumnHeaders, ch
    ColumnHeaders = Array("Számlanév", "Aktuális dátum", "Nettó számla érték", "Nettó nem realizált hozam", "Havi nettó realizált hozam", "Havi tranzfer saját számlák között", "Havi jövedelem", "Havi költés")

    Set SourceTable = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table2")
    Set TargetTable = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table3")
    TargetRow = TargetTable.ListRows.Add.Range.Row - 1
    For Each ch In ColumnHeaders
        SourceTable.ListColumns(ch).DataBodyRange.Copy TargetTable.ListColumns(ch).DataBodyRange.Cells(TargetRow)
    Next
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

A faster was is to us an array to transfer all the data at once.

```
Sub TransferRowsByArray()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim SourceTable As Excel.ListObject, TargetTable As Excel.ListObject
    Dim col As Integer, x As Long
    Dim ColumnHeaders, ch, Data
    ColumnHeaders = Array("Számlanév", "Aktuális dátum", "Nettó számla érték", "Nettó nem realizált hozam", "Havi nettó realizált hozam", "Havi tranzfer saját számlák között", "Havi jövedelem", "Havi költés")

    Set SourceTable = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    Set TargetTable = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2")

    ReDim Data(1 To SourceTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, 1 To SourceTable.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count)

    For Each ch In ColumnHeaders
        col = TargetTable.ListColumns(ch).Index

        With SourceTable.ListColumns(ch).DataBodyRange
            For x = 1 To .Rows.Count
                Data(x, col) = .Cells(x).Formula
            Next
        End With
    Next

    With TargetTable.ListRows.Add
        .Range.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This helped a lot, I am at 10 sec now: Application.ScreenUpdating = False

It is possible to copy columns at this example, this will speed up the macro even more. Still it seems strange that 130 individual copy takes, 10 sec.

Comment: @IstvanHeckl  You switch worksheets twice for every column. Without `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, Excel has to build a complete new window for each switch and then maintain the new window as you copy values.

Comment: Thanks @TonyDallimore.  In case you are interested, I posted a faster solution

Comment: @IstvanHeckl I'm surprised that it's taking 10 secs that's way too long for a couple hundred cells,. You must have a lot of formulas.  I added another  method to my answer that uses arrays.  I also modified both methods so that they turn off calculations.  This will give you a big performance boost, if you have a lot of formulas.

Comment: @IstvanHeckl you should watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ) and [Part 6 - Worksheets, Charts and Sheets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3OE7Z62oGM&list=PLd35hkENxNX12-DhbL771xf8fTSRpUv0F&index=6)